# After Hibernate migration from 4 to 5 OneToOne relationship causes ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, migration

We have such `OneToOne` bidirectional relationship:

```
class Student:

    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private StudentState state;

    public Student() {
        super();
        state = new StudentState(this);
    }

    public StudentState getState() {
        return state;
    }

class StudentState:

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student")
    private Student student;

    @Column(name = "inactive")
    private Boolean isInactive = false;

    public StudentState() {
    }

    public StudentState(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public boolean isInactive() {
        if (isInactive == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return isInactive;
    }

    public void setIsInactive(boolean isInactive) {
        this.isInactive = isInactive;
    }
```

And the following code we used to create the Student:

```
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

Student student = new Student();
session.save(student);
student.getState().setIsInactive(true);

t.commit();
```

The code worked fine in Hibernate 4. 
In Hibernate 5 it crashes with `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`
error.

Enabling "Show sql" showed that on the transaction commit hibernate tries to execute `insert StudentState` query before `insert Student` query. It causes:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: insert or update on table "studentstate" violates foreign key constraint "fk77j3mjaigcfotxlor35mdsl56"'
Detail: Key (student)=(12) is not present in table "students".
```

Any ideas why it happens, why it worked before and how to fix it? TIA

Comment: Has your DB schema changed at all? It sure sounds like the constraint is being checked on insert and not on commit...

Comment: The db schema is the same. The only thing that was changed is hibernate 4 library was changed to hibernate 5 as well as dependencies (jpa, ehcache etc)

Comment: Is there a way that hibernate is committing early?

Comment: Found a bug in hibernate, which caused insert statements to switch in some case where the statements shouldn't be switched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the problem is a bug in hibernate core. Class org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.
Here is the code after my fix:

```
            boolean hasAnyParentEntityNames(BatchIdentifier batchIdentifier) {
                return parentEntityNames.contains(batchIdentifier.getEntityName())
                        || parentEntityNames.contains(batchIdentifier.getRootEntityName());
            }

            boolean hasAnyChildEntityNames(BatchIdentifier batchIdentifier) {
                return childEntityNames.contains(batchIdentifier.getEntityName())
                        || childEntityNames.contains(batchIdentifier.getRootEntityName());
            }
```

Here is the code which was there before:

```
        boolean hasAnyParentEntityNames(BatchIdentifier batchIdentifier) {
            return parentEntityNames.contains(batchIdentifier.getEntityName())
                    || parentEntityNames.contains(batchIdentifier.getRootEntityName());
        }

        boolean hasAnyChildEntityNames(BatchIdentifier batchIdentifier) {
            return childEntityNames.contains(batchIdentifier.getEntityName())
                    || parentEntityNames.contains(batchIdentifier.getRootEntityName());
        }
```

Someone used wrong list to look for children and in some cases the method returned opposite value.